# QDomDocument - how to create from QString?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

How to create `QDomDocument` from `QString`, what contains many `XML` nodes?

I know one way - `setContent` method. But it's not better way - if I need to create `XML` from string with content like

```
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
    <calories>950</calories>
</food>
```

I need to pass to the setContent string like

```
    rhythmdb.setContent("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
                       " <breakfast_menu>"+res+"</breakfast_menu");
```

It's not good way - to specify xml version and encoding from the setContent.
As I imagine a right decision:

1. I need to create `QDomDocument rhythmdb;`
2. Specify `XML` version and encoding for rhythmdb
3. Create child element like `QDomElement childElement= rhythmdb.createElement("breakfast_menu");`
4. Append `XML` content of the `breakfast_menu` element, like `childElement.setContent(res);`

But there are no `setContent` method for `QDomElement` object.

How I can to program this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Doubt it matters in this particular case, but if you're going to specify the type of encoding for `QString` you'd might as well go ahead and specify the correct one: **UTF-16**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surveying the documentation, it does seem you really can only convert a QString into an entire QDomDocument.  You can't load it as QDomNode(s) into an existing one.

You can--however--copy loaded nodes between QDomDocuments with [QDomDocument::importNode()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#importNode).  So for mixing material from different source QStrings you can `setContent()` on a temporary document, and then import any of its desired node(s) into your target document.  After the import, insert these local copies where you want.

In your case, that won't help you use your string in its current form.  It is a series of siblings with no singular root element.  And QDomDocument only takes a `setContent()` from valid XML, as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element):

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements.

Thus if `setContent()` is your only string-to-XML mechanism, you will need to wrap it in a single parent before loading.  Prepending it with `<breakfast_menu>` and appending it with `</breakfast_menu>` seems fine for getting it in shape with a proper ROOT.

**BUT** don't worry about the [`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`](https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml):

- The encoding at time of input is only relevant when loading from a byte stream.  You're loading from a QString, where the decoding has already been done...(correctly or incorrectly).  It's [Unicode code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) by then and whatever you say the encoding is will have zero effect.
- If you want the XML declaration on your *output*, you have to add it manually in Qt anyway.  By default it's not included, and has to be specified explicitly with [QDomDocument::createProcessingInstruction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#createProcessingInstruction).  That's partially because the spec says it is optional, and partially because there will never be another XML standard, anyway.  ;-)